# move small menu icon to right beside logo

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

I think my eyes just hurt looking at this and I am not seeing the solution. When in the small breakpoint on Tailwind, I need the logo on the left and the 3 bar icon on the right. Nothing I do seems to make that happen. Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong please. Code below

```
<div class="md:h-16 bg-gray-100 dark:bg-gray-900">
            <div class="font-logo font-black max-w-7xl mx-auto py-4 px-4 sm:px-6 md:flex md:items-center md:justify-between lg:px-8">
                <div class="-mr-2 -my-2 md:hidden order-2 flex sm:justify-end md:justify-center space-x-6">
                    <PopoverButton class="rounded-md p-2 inline-flex items-center justify-center text-gray-100 hover:text-red-500 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-inset focus:ring-red-500">
                        <span class="sr-only">Open menu</span>
                        <MenuIcon class="h-6 w-6" aria-hidden="true" />
                    </PopoverButton>
                </div>
                <div class="hidden md:visible flex justify-center space-x-6 md:order-2">
                <Link v-if="$page.props.user" :href="route('dashboard')" class="text-sm text-gray-700 dark:text-gray-100">
                    Dashboard
                </Link>

                <template v-else>
                    <Link :href="route('login')" class="inline-flex items-center px-3 py-2 border border-transparent text-xs font-black rounded-full shadow-sm text-white bg-red-600 hover:bg-red-800 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-offset-2 focus:ring-red-500">
                        LOGIN
                    </Link>

                    <Link v-if="canRegister" :href="route('register')" class="ml-4 text-sm text-gray-100 pt-2 dark:text-gray-100">
                        REGISTER
                    </Link>
                </template>

                </div>
                <div class="tracking-wider uppercase flex sm:justify-start md:justify-center text-2xl mt-4 md:mt-0 md:order-1 font-logo">
                    <div class="text-white">REALKINK</div><div class="text-red-600">MEN</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Can you please provide something that I can run myself

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: You could probably remove the `md:` from `flex` and `justify-between` that's all that is keeping your header from using flex on small screen sizes.

Comment: @JHeth That solved it - if you turn it into a solution ill mark it as acceptable - thanks so much you rock!!!